# Trouble with Action arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, unity-game-engine, action

So I made a class that will store many methods. Then call them.
(ignore the Unity 3D as this is a c# question)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

namespace Beast.Extensions
{

public class MethodList : MonoBehaviour
{

    public MethodList (params System.Action[] _methods)
    {
        this.methods = new Action[_methods.Length];
    }

    public Action[] methods { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls a specific method in the list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="method"></param>
    public void Call (int method)
    {
        this.methods[method]();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls all of the methods in this method group in order.
    /// </summary>
    public void CallAll()
    {
        int l = this.methods.Length;
        for (int x = 0; x < l; x++)
        {
            this.methods[x]();
        }
    }


    }
}
```

And here is how I'm using it and calling it.

```
 MethodList deathMethods = new MethodList(() =>  print("Killing"), () => print("Dead"), () => Debug.Log("Dead a while ago."), () => print("Officially dead"));


deathMethods.Call(0); //Expected output: Killing
deathMethods.CallAll(); //Expected output: "Killing Dead a while ago Officially dead"
```

Error for all of them:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: You initialize `methods` as an empty `Action[]` in the constructor, but you never actually assign the methods to it

Comment: I'm sorry not sure what you mean?

Comment: `new Action[_methods.Length];` = empty array with the same capacity as your params

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public MethodList(params Action[] methods)
{
    Methods = methods;
}
public void Call(int num) =>  Methods[num]();
public void CallAll()
{
    foreach (var method in Methods) method();
}
```

You have to set `this.Methods` equal to `method`. You were only create an array of size `_method` but you didn't do anything with `this.Methods` so it remained `null`, nor did you do anything with the values stored in `_method`

You can also add an indexer, like so:

```
public Action this[int index]
{
    get { return Methods[index]; }
    set { Methods[index] = value; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
methodList[2] = () => Console.WriteLine("Alive again");
methodList[2]();
```